# Render React nested components

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to render the children of a React component under different divs?

```
<Page>
   <Header> ... </Header>
   <Content> ... </Content>
   <Actions> ... </Actions>
</Page>

<div class="page">
   <div class="header-wrapper>
      <div class="header"> ... </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="content"> ... </div>
      <div class="actions"> ... </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here I need the wrappers because the header is laid out differently from the area where content and actions are.

The obvious solution may be to introduce a Body component, but is there a more elegant way to abstract the concrete div tree which is needed to represent a certain layout from the logical components (Header, Content, Actions) which the Page declares.

Another solution which works is to pass the Header, Content, and Actions as properties as suggested in the React documentation:

```
<Page
   header={
      <Header> ... </Header>
   }
   content={
      <Content> ... </Content>
   }
   actions={
      <Actions> ... </Actions>
   }
/>
```

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

React lets you access individual Children

```
<Page>
   <Header> ... </Header>
   <Content> ... </Content>
   <Actions> ... </Actions>
</Page>
```

Inside `<Page />` Component render

```
render() {
  // when multiple elements are passed children prop is an array.
  // extract each of the element passed from the array and place them     
  // wherever needed in the JSX
  const [HeaderView, ContentView, ActionsView] = this.props.children;

  <div class="page">
    <div class="header-wrapper>
      {HeaderView}
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      {ContentView}
      {ActionsView}
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Isn't that applicable only if all the children are present and only in the exact order? In the generic case an instance of Page may not have a Footer or lack Actions - I guess then children will have to be individually examined. Also I have a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987063/react-component-such-that-the-children-of-the-component-can-be-one-or-more-of-ce) about how to control what children are acceptable

Comment: @GeorgeS. the order definetely matters if u rely on children
but above code works even if traling elements are missing. if middle elements are missing pass empty <div />.
But i think `<Page />` is not a good abstraction for reusability as unless ur website is a content driven site than features. pages generally dont have exact same sections. So you better not have a component like <Page /> if ur sections vary drastically

Answer (score 0):

Use [React.Children.toArray](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.toarray) to convert your props.children (that is an opaque data structure) to an array and safely reorganize them.

After convert to array, you can use `find` or `forEach` methods to get each one - Header, Content and Action - by testing the type of the item.

```
const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
const headerView = children.find(child => child.type.name === 'HeaderView');
const contentView = children.find(child => child.type.name === 'ContentView');
const actionsView = children.find(child => child.type.name === 'ActionsView');

<div class="page">
  <div class="header-wrapper>
    {headerView}
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    {contentView}
    {actionsView}
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember to declare HeaderView, ContentView and ActionsView with class or function declaration, not anonymous functions like:

```
const HeaderView = props => {
  // some stateless rendering
};
```

Otherwise they might have no `type.name` to test against.

Answer (score -1):

In Aurelia, you can use named slots to achieve this result, but in react the best workaround I have found is to do this:

```
// ...

const header = <Header someProp={someVal} />;
const content = <Content someOtherProp={someOtherVal} />;
const actions = <Actions action1={someAction} action2={someOtherAction} />;

return (
  <Page header={header} content={content} actions={actions} />
);
```

and in page.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const Page = ({ header, content, actions }) => (
  <div className="page">
    <div className="header-wrapper">
      <div className="header">
        {header}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      <div className="content">
        {content}
      </div>
      <div className="actions">
        {actions}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

Page.propTypes = {
  header: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  content: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```