# React component such that the children of the component can be one or more of certain types

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to declare typechecking on a React component such that the children of the component can be one or more of certain types.

I followed the React documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and declared the expected propType to be an array of union of types but it seems this does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the code causes a runtime errors like

```
"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Body`."
```

Code:

```
function Body(props) {
  return React.Children.count(props.children) > 0 && (
    <div className="body">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

Body.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
    React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
      React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Content),
      React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Actions)
    ])
  )
};

<Body>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <Actions>...</Actions>
</Body>
```

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use

```
Body.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
      React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.node),
      React.PropTypes.node
    ])
};
```

This tells react that `children` can be one or more JSX nodes.

Comment: This doesn't validate if the children are  `Content` and `Actions`. This would blindly accept any kind of node.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Body.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
      type: React.PropTypes.oneOf([Content, Actions])
    })),
    React.PropTypes.shape({
      type: React.PropTypes.oneOf([Content, Actions])
    })
  ])
};
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/oz71mu6g/2/

---

`React.PropTypes.instanceOf` is actually implemented using JavaScript [`instanceOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), it is expecting a regular JavaScript "class" and not a React class. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2979).

Comment: Is there a way to allow empty/null children too... I tried adding "null" to the oneOfType() but it did not work. The documentation does not say anything about "null" or "empty"

Comment: But in your question you said "one or more of certain types". If you don't want it to warn for `null` then don't make it `isRequired`, it has the same effect.